# How to solve libcurl Errors in C (Curl_easy_perform 43)

Tags: c, libcurl

I was doing C application for posting json data to cloud using libcurl. But im getting error code curl_easy_perform 43.

my code is as below :

```
int HTTPConnection (char *Json_Data)
{
  int rc = 0;
  char Url[180];
  CURL *curl;
  struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
  strcpy (Url, "https://");
  strcat (Url, Host_Name);
  strcat (Url, "/devices/");
  strcat (Url, ID);
  strcat (Url, "/messages/events");
  strcat (Url, "?api-version=2016-02-03");
  printf ("\n\n URL = %s\n", Url);

  headers = curl_slist_append (headers, "Accept: application/json");
  headers = curl_slist_append (headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
  headers = curl_slist_append (headers, "Username: poc-iotconnect-iothub-eu.azure-devices.net/98f5b52a59aa4503999894c10bc33dca-Demo123/?api-version=2018-06-30");
  headers = curl_slist_append (headers, "Authorization : sas");

 rc = curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_URL, Url);
        printf ("\n curl_easy_setopt 1 %d -\n", rc);
 rc = curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        printf("\n curl_easy_setopt 2 %d -\n", rc);
  rc = curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Json_Data);
  printf ("\n curl_easy_setopt 3 %d -\n", rc);

  rc = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        printf("\n Curl_easy_perform %d -\n", rc);

  curl_slist_free_all (headers);
  return rc;
}

int main (void)
{
  int rc = 0, count = 0;
  rc = cloud_init ();
  if (rc != 0)
    printf ("\n Cloud_init failed.\n");
      Json_Data = Sensor_Data();
      rc = HTTPConnection(Json_Data);

      if (rc != 0)
        printf ("\n\n HTTP Connection Failed.. \n ");
    return ;
}
```

**Output :**

```
URL = https://poc-iotconnect-iothub-eu.azure-devices.net/devices/98f5b52a59aa4503999894c10bc33dca-Demo123/messages/events?api-version=2016-02-03
 curl_easy_setopt 1 43 -
 curl_easy_setopt 2 43 -
 curl_easy_setopt 3 43 -
 Curl_easy_perform 43 -
 HTTP Connection Failed..
```

Why i am getting curl error 43? how to solve that error ? anyone knows please help me..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You forgot to initialise `curl`. https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Without looking deeply into the code, the posted code is missing all the `#include` statements for the needed header files.   Are you expecting us to reverse engineer your code to determine which header files are needed?

Comment: the posted, even after inserting the needed `#include` statements does not compile!   Amongst other problems, in function: `main()` this statement: `return ;`  is not valid.  Either remove that statement or append a value to be returned

Comment: where is the function: `sensor_data()`?

Comment: regarding: `strcat (Url, Host_Name);`  the string: `Host_Name[]` not declared anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: regarding: `strcat (Url, ID);` the string: `ID[]` not declared anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.